# how can i get run sql like 'show create table xxx' in knexjs

Tags: knex.js

is there anyone know how to run sql like 'show create table xxx' in knex.js?
And how can i get the result?

write like this ?

```js
knex.schema.raw('show create table xxx');
```

and another question how to write "replace into " in knexjs?

Comment: is `knex.schema.raw('show create table xxx');` doesn't works?